# Disable Virtual Consoles

Tags: linux, console, virtual-console

We have an embedded Linux system running Redhat 6.5. We would like to disable virtual consoles, so the user is unable to navigate away from our application. I've found some references to editing files in /etc/init, but none of the examples I've found seem to correspond to our system.

If maintenance is necessary, we would prefer to ssh in from another machine. Our goal is to do away with virtual consoles altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion on Fedora forum might help:
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=251849